# How to truncate a Postgresql's table from JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a Postgresql database and I want to truncate some tables using JDBC. How do I do that?

This is what I tried, but none worked... without even any error being reported:

Using `CallableStatement`.

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
     CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("TRUNCATE " + tableName)) {
  return statement.execute();
}
```

Using `Statement`.

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
     Statement statement  = connection.createStatement()) {
  return statement.execute("TRUNCATE " + tableName);
}
```

Using `PreparedStatement`.

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
     PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("TRUNCATE " + tableName)) {
  return statement.execute();
}
```

Comment: `CallableStatement` is used to invoke stored procedure inside DB. `TRUNCATE` is not a SP, hence, it should not work. What error did you get when you used plain `Statement`? You can also enable `JDBC driver` tracing to check what is happening inside.

Comment: No error was ever reported. For any of the tries. How can I enable that JDBC tracing?

Comment: Looks like your errors are getting swalloed somewhere in the client code. Put a `catch(Exception e) {e.printStacktrace();}` block before finally. You can enable tracing by following `DriverManager.setLogWriter()` API or refer to actual Driver guide. What JDBC Driver you are using

Comment: No, the exceptions are not swallowed. I changed the code in the 2nd try to be: `boolean result = statement.execute("TRUNCATE " + tableName); System.out.println("Everything is ok"); return result;` and I see "Everything is ok" on the console. 
Thanks for the info about the info on logwriter. I'm using the driver `org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc4` (retrieved from Maven).
Right now you're focusing on the wrong part. Don't tell me what I do wrong, please tell me how to do it properly, how you would do it yourself.

Comment: Use `Statement.executeUpdate` method instead of `execute`.

Comment: Then, how do you know it is not actually truncating the table? Instead of `execute()` try calling `executeUpdate()` and check the count returned from Statement object.

Comment: Truncate throws an SQLException when it fails, if you don't get any exception, it means that it succeeded.

Comment: `Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); statement.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE " + tableName); System.out.println("OK")` still doesn't work and yet still prints "OK". Bimalesh, I know the truncate doesn't work because the table has over 500 records where I only insert 100. If I truncate properly the table should have only 100 records. Just like when I do it directly in the database. Do I have to commit or something right after a truncate?

Comment: Yes, I need to commit. Final answer. It works now.

Comment: Your code doesn't have `catch` section and simply ignores all errors, you must catch the exception and check error codes/messages.

Comment: @kordirko, if I see the "OK", then that means that no exception is thrown. My error handling is done in the wrapping method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After the truncate, I need to commit:

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection();
     Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
  int result = statement.executeUpdate("TRUNCATE " + tableName);
  connection.commit();
  return result;
}
```

From [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-truncate.html):

> TRUNCATE is transaction-safe with respect to the data in the tables: the truncation will be safely rolled back if the surrounding transaction does not commit.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"TRUNCATE TABLE " + tableName`?

Comment: @Marteng [No, according to the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html)

Answer (score 4):

You may run into issues if the table has dependencies.  If so, truncate the parent tables first, and also use the CASCADE option.

```
Connection connection = getConnection();
try {
    PreparedStatement statement  = connection.prepareStatement("TRUNCATE " + parentTable1, parentTable2, ... + " CASCADE");
    try {
        return statement.execute();
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
} finally {
    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are truncating a table, you probably want to also RESTART IDENTITY (in addition to possibly doing CASCADE, as John Hogan mentioned).

Second, as far as doing a connection.commit(), the assumption is that you have autocommit set to OFF. My Postgres was set up with it set to ON (apparently, that is sometimes the default).
If it is set to ON, then calling the commit is unnecessary, and will result in the error:
"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled."

Third, you may not have permission to truncate a table (or restart identity). In that case, you will need to:

```
DELETE from your_table
SELECT setval('your_table_id', 1)
```

The following worked for me:

```
public String truncateTable(String tableName, boolean cascadeFlag) {
    String message = "";
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String truncation = "TRUNCATE TABLE yourSchema." + tableName + " RESTART IDENTITY" + (cascadeFlag ? " CASCADE" : "");
        System.out.println("truncateTable: Executing query '" + truncation + "'.");
        int result = statement.executeUpdate(truncation);
        // connection.commit();  // If autocommit is enabled (which it is for our DB), then throws exception after truncating the table.
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        message = "Could not truncate table " + tableName + ". " + sqlex.getMessage();
        System.err.println(message);
        sqlex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return message;
}
```

Also:

```
public int deleteResetTable(String tableName, String fieldName) {
        int affectedRows = 0;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            String sql = "DELETE FROM yourSchema." + tableName;
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Deleted " + affectedRows+ " rows from table " + tableName + ".");
            sql = "SELECT setval('yourSchema." + fieldName + "', 1)";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Reset " + affectedRows+ " values from table " + tableName + ".");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to delete rows from " + tableName + " " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return affectedRows;
}
```